# Mysqli query not working properly in if/else statement

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table in MySQL and I want to check in PHP whether there are any 'tasks' written (it's a todo list webapp). If there aren't I want to display a message 'You haven't added any tasks yet', problem is it's not displaying.

PHP is assuming that the list of tasks is never empty, when for user 1 (in PHP current user_id = 2), for instance, it is, since I haven't inserted any tasks in my MySQL for User 1 (all tasks are user 2).

```
<?php
global $connection;
$user = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM to_do_list WHERE user = $user";
$items = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>

            <div>
                <?php if(!empty($items)): ?>    
                <ul id="myUL">
                    <?php foreach($items as $item):  ?>  
                    <li>
                        <span class="item<?php echo $item['done'] ? ' done' : '' ?>"><?php echo $item['task']; ?></span>
                        <?php if(!$item['done']): ?>
                        <a href="#" class="donebutton">Done</a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php else: ?>
                <p>You haven't added any tasks yet.</p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqli_query returns a "resource" not an array - so:

instead of `foreach($items as $item):` use `while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items))`

and now every `$item` is an associated array of results (meaning - you can call the output using it's name like `$item['done']`)

also - instead of `if(!empty($items))` you should use `if(mysqli_num_rows($items) > 0)`

Comment: it's fun to be helpful :) have a nice day!